# Would it make sense to have separate tags for brown bears and black bears?

Tags: discussion

My meta question is prompted by this old question [Will a tent provide some protection from bears?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/418/will-a-tent-provide-some-protection-from-bears) which resurfaced when a new answer came in.  I know it is too late to differentiate on old questions, but, assuming new bear questions will be coming in, can we somehow avoid lumping brown and black bears together in questions and answers?

Comment: Probably, yes. I don't see a problem with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If questions are about bears in general, then the **bears** tag should be employed.

That said and seeing that there are [eight species of bears in the world,](http://bearwithus.org/8-bears-of-the-world/) it would be more than appropriate to have a separate tag for each species, providing that the question is asking something particular to the nature of that species.

The differences between bear species is quite amazing, but questions on the subspecies such as seen in this [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_bears) should remain within the scope of the bear species in question!